# Normal subgroup and order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a finite group and let $H$ be a normal subgroup. Prove that, for any $g\in G$, the order of the element $gH$ in $G/H$ must divide the order of $g$ in $G$.

All I have for this proof is; define the order of the element $gH$ as $n$ then this implies $g^nH = eH = H$.

How can I prove this in the most direct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with any group morphism: suppose $f : G \rightarrow G'$ and $g \in G$. Then the order of $f(g)$ divides the order of $g$. This is because if $g^n = e$, $f(g^n) = f(g)^n = e$, so that the order of $f(g)$ divides $n$.

Here, take as $f$ the natural projection: $f(g) = gH$.